# Cannot connect to "0.0.0.2 - Published app name" in Citrix Receiver (ICA Client 13.10.x)

Tags: ssl-certificate, desktop-application, fedora, citrix

If you want to establish a connection with the citrix receiver on different citrix-based vpn-services, then an error message appears "Connection with 0.0.0.2 ... cannot connect, no such file or directory"

Current configuration:

- Fedora 28 with all updates
- Browser Firefox 63.0
- ICAClient-13.10.0.20-0.x86_64

Answer (score 6):

```sh
cd /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/
sudo rm -rf cacerts
sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs cacerts
```

Comment: Some additional details as to why exactly you are doing in the commands would be helpful, especially since there is some `sudo rm -rf` going on :)

Answer (score 1):

Answers can be found in the ubuntu forum, but they didn't help me: [Citrix receiver error 1000119](https://askubuntu.com/questions/901448/citrix-receiver-error-1000119)

My problem are also the certificates ... the following root certificates: **Digicert** and **Comodo**

The technical solution to my problem is as follows - do it in the terminal as root.

```
su
cd /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/
wget https://dl.cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt
curl https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/GetAttachment/969/821026 > comodorsacertificationauthority.crt
exit
```

And connect the vpn-services again.

Comment: Hi Dierk. Thanks so much for sharing your fix. Unfortunately for me it didn't change anything, still the same error. Fedora 30, ICA 19.3

Comment: I have faced the same issue in Ubuntu, in my case I just changed my connection type from ipv4/ipv6 to ipv4 and its worked.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue in Ubuntu, in my case I just changed my connection type from ipv4/ipv6 to ipv4 and its worked.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me on ubuntu, by copying the certs (entire cacerts directory) to /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts from /etc/ssl/certs

Answer (score 0):

Just installed newest Receiver (now called **Workspace**) but it had same ssl certificate issue.
I recalled a 2013 fix I had used several years ago from AskUbuntu-> Make Firefox's certificates accessible to Citrix.
I suppose it has to do with certificates that my institution uses and aren't included in the usual Citrix downloads since most people are not screaming for a fix.

All you have to do is set a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts
```

or wherever your flavor's Citrix and mozilla certificates are stored...YMMV

Comment: This didn't work for me in ubuntu.